# Critical points vs inflection points

Tags: calculus

I came upon a question that asks to find a function which has a critical point at some coordinates and an inflection point at some other coordinates. I can't see exactly what is the difference between the two, could someone help clarify it to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Critical points** refer to the first derivative. In particular, $x=a$ is a critical point of $f(x)$ if either $f'(a)=0$ or $f'(a)$ is not defined. The importance here is that all maxima or minima are found at critical points or endpoints of a domain. So a common way to find extrema (maxima and minima) is to find the endpoints and critical points and see which of those are extrema.

**Inflection points** refer to the second derivative. In particular, $x=a$ is an inflection point of $f(x)$ if the second derivative of $f$ is positive in an interval immediately on one side of $a$ and negative in an interval immediately on the other side of $a$. (I believe it is also a condition that $f'(x)$ exists.) It is also true that either $f''(a)=0$ or $f''(a)$ is not defined, but those conditions are not enough to guarantee an inflection point. The importance here is that $f(x)$ is concave up (turning up) on one side of $x=a$ and concave down (turning down) on the other side of $x=a$.

Both critical points and inflection points have many other uses.

Comment: Consider a two valued function $f(x)= x^{\frac{3}{5}}$ for $x\leq 1$ and $f(x)=-(x-2)^{3}$ for $x>1$.  According to you $2,0$ will only be the critical points right .

Comment: But on careful examination we can find $f'(x)$ changes sign at $x=1$ and since slope sign changing means necessarily a critical point it should be a critical point . Or am i still wrong ?

Comment: @SujithZis: $x=0$ an inflection point of your function. $x=1$ is a critical point since $f'(x)$ is undefined there, but it is not an inflection point for the same reason. That last point is not emphasized but is present in [Wikipedia's definition of inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point). [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html) is ambiguous on that issue.

Comment: okay you are correct only point taken , will update answer .

Comment: Is inflection point a critical point?

Comment: @JohnStrood: The main point of my answer is that those are two different concepts. So any given point may be one but not the other, or both, or neither. So an inflection point may be a critical point (as in $y=x^3$) or it may not (as in $y=x^3+x$).

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

### Critical points

refers to the set of all points which satisfies at least one of the following conditions :

(A) $f'(x)=0$ ie: turning points.

(B) $f'(x)$ does not exist.

(C) sign changes of $f'(x)$ in nbd of $x$ (not a completely necessary condition as these will be included in (B))

Whereas

### Inflection points

are those points which satisfies atleast one of the following conditions :

(A) sign changes of $f''(x)$ in the neighbourhood of $x$ .

Comment: How can a critical point satisfy f'(x) = 0 and f'(x) does no exist at the same time??

Comment: Also, what do you mean by nbd?

Comment: For "critical points," $f(x)=\sqrt[3] x$ shows that the sign of $f'(x)$ does not necessarily change. A critical point merely has property (A) or (B). For "inflection points," $f(x))=\sqrt[3] x$ also shows that it is possible that $f''(x)$ does not exist. An inflection point merely has property (B).

Comment: @ArthurRimbaud i meant those as separate cases , i will update , nbd = neighbourhood

Comment: @RoryDaulton there are some particular exceptional cases where f'(x) sign change can mean a critical point

Comment: True, but all those cases are also included in either $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ undefined. Your cases (A) and (B) cover all possible critical points. At least, in the usual definition.